# Why would I get a syntax error on this pretty simple trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm getting a syntax error :

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure trgDiscoverSurchargeChangeTiming, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'

on a trigger I'm writing.  Now, I normally avoid triggers because I tend to forget them later when I am making changes to the DB, so I'm a little rusty on them, but I feel like this one should be fine:

```
(TRIGGER STUFF)Begin

if update(surchargepay)
    begin
        insert into 
            dbo.CustomErrorLog 
                (errorText
                , ErrorOrderID
                , errorOldValue
                , errorNewValue) 
        values 
            select -- This is where the error is being thrown
                convert(varchar(50), getdate())
                , i.routeid
                , d.surchargepay
                , i.surchargepay 
            from 
                inserted i INNER JOIN 
                deleted d on i.id = d.id
    end

End
```

any ideas what might cause that?

Comment: Take the `values` out....

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the "value" keyword when using "select" to populate an insert.